# How do I get details for the products that were ordered on the success page in Magento?

Tags: magento, product

I was able to get order details and customer details inside template/checkout/success.html file, but not sure how to get details for the exact products that were ordered? I need their names for some third party stat appliances. I bet it's simple - just another weird chained call to some "where-did-this-come-from?" method...

Help?

Comment: Complete Solution is posted in below link. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/293713/#t407228 Thanks, Kashif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do (as you have order model)

```
$order_items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($order_items as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    //and you can do what ever you want with the product
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about $item->getProductId()? As I did a printout of the available methods on the item and I can't see getProductId in the list. Only getProductOptions..?

Comment: getProductId() is parsed by magento's magic functions... i.e. it would do the same thing if you do $item->getData('product_id');

Comment: try printing out $item->getData() you would get a list of values it is holding.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the order details like:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout  /session')->getLastOrderId());
```

Then you can pull in all the various data with this:

```
$subtotal = $order->getSubtotal();
$order->getId();
$order->getIncrementId();
$order->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: I got that info already. I was searching for a way to retrieve info for products in the order.

Comment: `foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
        {
        $name[] = $item->getName();
        $unitPrice[]=$item->getPrice();
        $sku[]=$item->getSku();
        $ids[]=$item->getProductId();
        $qty[]=$item->getQtyToInvoice();
    }`